# Switch turns in a 2v2 game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am building a turn based game with two sides. Each side can have up to two or more players. How do I alternate the turns in the game?

When I have one player on each side, the solution is simple. But when I have more than one player the solution gets more complicated and I have not been able to figure it out.

This is the shape of my 2D array.

```
Player[] side1 = new Player[] { "A", "B" };
Player[] side2 = new Player[] { "X", "Y" };
Player[][] allSides = new Player[][] {
    side1,
    side2
};
```

I want to switch the turn for each side each time, getting the next player in each side's array. I'm aiming to get the following results to be returned:

1st turn: `return allSides[0][0]; // returns side 1 Player A`

2nd turn: `return allSides[1][0]; // returns side 2 Player X`

3rd turn: `return allSides[0][1]; // returns side 1 Player B`

4th turn: `return allSides[1][1]; // returns side 2 Player Y`

...

nth turn: `return allSides[i][j]`

and basically have that pattern occur in order throughout the rest of the game.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple - just use the last two bits of the `turn` as the indices into your array. As you start from 0 and increment by 1, your last two bit will form this sequence:

```
00
01
10
11
00
01
10
11
... - and so on.
```

Now just use the last bit as your first array index and the second bit as the second array index - something like this:

```
int turn = 0;
boolean gameOver = false;

Player currentPlayer;
while (!gameOver) {
    currentPlayer = allSides[turn & 1][(turn & 2) >> 1]
    ...
    turn++;
}
```

If you need your turn to start with 1 instead of 0, then simply subtract 1 from `turn` when calculating your indices:

```
currentPlayer = allSides[(turn -1) & 1][((turn - 1) & 2) >> 1]
```